# FluentEmail render ignore unmapped properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We are currently using FluentEmail's RazorRenderer to construct emails and have placedholders in them replaced by a model:

```
await razor.ParseAsync(emailContent, placeholderData);
```

where emailContent is a string of data which can contain placeholder's like @Model.FirstName and placeholderData has a property called FirstName which get replaced fine.

However, if there is a placeholder which does not exist in the placeholderData the ParseAsync errors, is there a way to get it to just ignore the ones it can not map?

We are using Razor Renderer:

```
var razor = new RazorRenderer();
```

emailContent in the above comes from the database, these are strings of html which the user builds with a rich text editor.  The editor allows them to add placeholders within the html, something like:

> Thank you @Model.FirstName for submitting!

Incase they end up using something that is not valid, for example @Model.FrstName, is there a way to avoid the ParseAsync from throwing an error.  As the editor does allow the user to edit the content as they make it, so they could mistype the property name.

Comment: Could the email content be a cshtml file and you can check in there if the element exists in there? Also pass in an object which could have 'null' elements

Comment: I think some more code would help here - are you using a Liquid template or razor?

Comment: @RichardHousham will update the post, using Razor.  the templates are strings coming from the db, so not cshtml file as they are built by the users of the system.